# Obtener valores de una tabla y convertirlo en array

Tags: html, jquery, array

Tengo una tabla como la siguiente, en la cual se insertan datos, lo que quiero lograr es que al momento de presionar el boton se forme un arreglo el cual contenga cuatro arreglos cada uno de ellos con el valor de cada uno de los inputs.

El arreglo que necesito formar quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
prametros = [
             0:[dato1: "xvalor", dato2: "xvalor",dato3: "xvalor",dato4: "xvalor", dato5: "xvalor"],
             1:[dato1: "xvalor", dato2: "xvalor",dato3: "xvalor",dato4: "xvalor", dato5: "xvalor"],
             2:[dato1: "xvalor", dato2: "xvalor",dato3: "xvalor",dato4: "xvalor", dato5: "xvalor"],
             3:[dato1: "xvalor", dato2: "xvalor",dato3: "xvalor",dato4: "xvalor", dato5: "xvalor"],
            ]
```

tengo el siguiente código peor no hace lo que necesito alguien que me pueda ayudar se lo agradecería mucho.

```js
$("#btn-nuevo").click(function(){
            var parametros=[];
            var parame=[];
            $("table tbody tr").each(function(i,e){
                parametro = {    
                  "dato1" : $(this).val(),
                  "dato2" : $(this).val(),
                  "dato3" : $(this).val(),
                  "dato4" : $(this).val(),
                  "dato5" : $(this).val()
                }      
                
            });
            parametros.push(parametro);
            alert(parametros);
            console.log(parametros);

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" border "1">
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <td>Opciones</td>
        <td>Dato 1</td>
        <td>Dato 2</td>
        <td>Dato 3</td>
        <td>Dato 4</td>
        <td>Dato 5</td>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td>Opcion 1</td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control requerido"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido" ></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Opcion 2</td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control requerido"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Opcio 3</td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control requerido" ></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido" ></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Opcion 4</td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control requerido" ></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido"></td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
        <button id="btn-nuevo" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom:10px">
                 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                 Agregar
             </button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estas bien cerca. Solo tienes que recorrer los `td` de cada `tr` y agregar los `td` a un array de `tr`. Tambien hay que ignorar el primer indice de cada `tr` que son los que dicen Opcion 1, Opcion 2, etc., etc.

Aqui el codigo:

```js
$("#btn-nuevo").click(function(){
            var parametros=[];
            var parame=[];
            $("table tbody tr").each(function(i,e){
            
                var tr = [];
                $(this).find("td").each(function(index, element){
                    if(index != 0) // ignoramos el primer indice que dice Option #
                    {
                    var td = {};
                    td["dato"+index] = $(this).find("input").val();
                    tr.push(td);
                    }
                });
                parametros.push(tr);    
            });
            
            console.log(parametros);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" border "1">
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <td>Opciones</td>
        <td>Dato 1</td>
        <td>Dato 2</td>
        <td>Dato 3</td>
        <td>Dato 4</td>
        <td>Dato 5</td>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td>Opcion 1</td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control requerido"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido" ></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Opcion 2</td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control requerido"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Opcio 3</td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control requerido" ></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido" ></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Opcion 4</td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control requerido" ></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control requerido"></td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
        <button id="btn-nuevo" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom:10px">
                 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                 Agregar
             </button>
```

Comment: Gracias, amigo. :D